# Getting the last column of a grep match for each line

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

Let's say I have

```
this is a test string
this is a shest string
this est is another example of sest string
```

*I want the number of the character in string of the last "**t**" IN THE WORDS [tsh]EST, how do I get it?* (In bash)
EDIT2: I can get the wanted substring with [tsh]*est if I'm not wrong.

I cannot rely on the first match (awk where=match(regex,$0) ) since it gives the first character position but the size of the match is not always the same.

EDIT: Expected output ->

```
last t of [tsh]*est at char number: 14
last t of [tsh]*est at char number: 15
last t of [tsh]*est at char number: 35
```

Hope I was clear, I think I edited the question too many times sorry !

Comment: This is why I would use regex before to match [tsh]*est before and then my problem would become: "how to find last column in a variable size grep match?" Sorry for enraveling the question

Comment: Do you mean position of the line, or column?

Comment: isn't it the same thing? position of the line anyway

Comment: No, with this test: `What is wrong`, you find `r` on location `10` on the line, and in column `3`, not the same number.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought they were "fields", edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What you got wrong**

```
where=match(regex,$0)
```

the syntax of match is wrong. its string followd by the regex. That is `match($0, regex)`

**Correction**

```
$ awk '{print match($0, "t[^t]*$")}' input
17
18
38
```

**EDIT**

Get  number of the character in string of the last "t" IN THE WORDS [tsh]EST,

```
$ awk '{match($0, "(t|sh|s)est"); print RSTART+RLENGTH-1}' input
14
15
35
```

OR

a much simpler version

```
$ awk 'start=match($0, "(t|sh|s)est")-1{$0=start+RLENGTH}1' input
    14
    15
    35
```

Thanks Jidder for the suggestion

**EDIT**

To use the regex **same as OP has provided**

```
$ awk '{for(i=NF; match($i, "(t|sh|s)*est") == 0 && i > 0; i--); print index($0,$i)+RLENGTH-1;}' input
14
15
35
```

Comment: yeah it was only an example, not wanted to use right syntax ^_^ 
Anyway this will get the last "t" of the line, I actually want the last "t" of the words [tsh]*est

Comment: Could be reduced to `awk 'x=match($0,"(t|sh|s)est")-1{$0=x+RLENGTH}1' file`

Comment: @Jidder nice !! will add to the answer :)

Comment: OP's regex is actually `[tsh]*est` which will not give this output since that will match multiple times in last line.

Comment: Actually it does match, in last line it matches `est` after `this ` and then it matches `sest` so giving output as 35

Comment: This regex `[tsh]*est` does match `sest` since `*` means 0 or more matches

Comment: @anubhava sorry if am slow to follow. `[tsh]*est` should match both `est`(zero occurent) and `sest`(one occurence of s) right?

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying that `[tsh]*est` will match `est` and `sest` both and since OP wants **last occurrence of t** hence last position of `t` in `sest` which is `35` should be printed in output.

Comment: @anubhava got you. so if some `est` follows `test` then my script would fail

Comment: Yes that's right. I edited my answer below, which is a bit more code due to this requirement only.

Comment: @anubhava i think i got a simpler script. suggest me if you find some loopholes :) Thank you

Comment: I believe it should work but not sure if it is simpler since it is searching regex twice for each field using `match` and `index`. If line is big in size then this can cause some slowness.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk using **same regex as provided by OP**:

```
awk -v re='[tsh]*est' '{
    i=0;
    s=$0;
    while (p=match(s, re)) {
       p+=RLENGTH;
       i+=p-1;
       s=substr(s, p)
    }
    print i;
}' file
14
15
35
```

Comment: Clever, but could be fooled by repeated strings.

Comment: Yes @tripleee, It took me sometime to understand OP's requirement clearly. It is edited now to take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
awk '{for (i=NF;i>=0;i--) { if(index ($i, "t") != 0) {print i; break}}}' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print the column with the last word that contains  `t`

```
awk '{s=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/t/) s=i;print s}' file
5
5
8
```

---

```
awk '{s=w=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/t/) {s=i;w=$i};print "last t found in word="w,"column="s}'
last t found in word=string column=5
last t found in word=string column=5
last t found in word=string column=8
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to mention that it was not the last "t" in absolute, but the last "t" of the word matching [tsh]*est